# Django not loading static CSS file

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I have looked around on this site as well as others and still have not found a solution that works for why django is not loading my css file

my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

in my html file:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/my_style.css' %}">
```

My file tree:

```
todo_app
    static
    todo_app
    todo_list
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'todo_list',
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried using the STATIC_ROOT as shown on a different thread but there was no change with that.

Comment: Something says to me you should remove the first slash `/` in `/css/my...`

Comment: just tried that, still no change unfortunately

Comment: What happens when you check the source code in the browser, does it open the css link or says file not found?

Comment: It was saying the file was not found. Another member just helped me get it figured out though. I just needed to move the static directory within the app todo_list

Answer (score 6):

Same Issue,
Tried Crazy Solutions for 1 hour,

**Found Problem** : Browser cachs the css template and need to manually cleared to view the Updated CSS view.

Simple restarting the `python manage.py runserver`
and

Opening the template in **chrome's incognito mode**  solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

settings.py

```
# ....
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# ....

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


# ......


urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I added the STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root') to the settings.py and then added the missing imports and urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) to the urls.py. I put the new statement in the urls.py under the existing ones I already had in there. Is that correct or does it need to be within?

Comment: urlpatterns = [ ] add after

Comment: my django starter project link : https://github.com/ozkansen/Django-Starter-Project

Comment: Ok, I added it just like your example but there is still no change. When I do a view page source on the site after I run the server I am still seeing "css/my_style.css; could not be found"

Comment: I tried that, it compiled a bunch of files into a static_root folder. Still no luck. I am getting that same error

Comment: Can you upload to project on github?

Comment: that worked! thank you very much for your help. So do I need to do a static folder within the specific app going forward?

Comment: You can define in settings.py. For example, if you define DIRS in the template as 'DIRS': [os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'templates')], you can move the static and templates folder to the parent folder.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same problem and in my case, I solved with hard refresh.

1. Stop the server with CTRL+C
2. Update you CSS or load your CSS.
3. Start the server with `python manage.py runserver`
4. If you are using Chrome click `CTRL + F5` for hard refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem. Manually restarting the server fixed it. In the terminal running the server use:

`Ctrl-c`

`python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

add following in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

also, remove slash '/' from href, it should be"{% static 'css/my_style.css' %}"

Answer (score 0):

I had also this problem.I again restart my server and it was fixed. I was stuck here. But after doing this it works perfectly.

```
> ctrl-c
> python3 manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score -1):

`{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/my_style.css' %}">`

remove slash '/'